# JUnit 4.xx (Java) Trouble with Mockito when Trying to Get Line Coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

**The following is my main code.**

```
public class KafkaConsumerForTests {

private ConsumerRecords<String, String> records;
private GenericKafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            while (true) {

               LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "Attempting to Poll");
               records = consumer.poll(10000);
               int numOfRecords = records.count();

               **if (numOfRecords == 0) {** // I want to get line coverage for this branch

                LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "No Response. Invalid Topic");
                break;
            }

            **else if(numOfRecords > 0) {** // I want to get line coverage for this branch.

                LOGGER.logp(Level.INFO, CLASS_NAME, "run()", "Response Received");
            }
        }

    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        consumer.close();
    }

  }

}
```

As you can see I want to get line coverage for the following branches to test if it's correctly logging. I tried mocking out instances of records.count(); **You can see my code for the test case below.**

```
@Test
public void testRunWithZeroRecords() throws IOException {

    KafkaConsumerForTests consumerThread3 = spy(new KafkaConsumerForTests("topic_pleasestuff", "lmao"));

    ConsumerRecords<String, String> mock2 = mock(ConsumerRecords.class);

    consumerThread3.records = mock2;

    when(mock2.count()).thenReturn(9);

    consumerThread3.run();

    //verify(mock2, times(1)).count();
}
```

No matter what I do, I'm not hitting:

> else if(numOfRecords > 0)

I am returning a number greater than 0. It's as if ***records.count();*** isn't even being executed in the mock. I apologize for any convention or StackOverflow question syntax errors. I'm new to the Java community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mock2.count()` isn't happening, because ahead of the call to `count()` in the method you're testing, you reassign `records` to the result of `consumer.poll(10000);`.

You'll need to create mocks, say `mockRecords` and `mockConsumer`; and then inject `consumer` with the mock that you created.  Then include a stub line like

```
doReturn(mockRecords).when(mockConsumer).poll(10000);
```

before your call to `run`.